# Powershell disable devices in BIOS

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a solution which can be applied in Bios on a HP-Device.

The Script should disable: WLAN, Bluetooth, Webcam and the microfone.

That's what I tried so far:

[image: This is what I've tried]

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify BIOS settings through Win32. You'd need a special driver for that that would be provided by HP, if it exists.

Something like http://whp-aus2.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/whitepapers/HP_BCU_FAQ.pdf maybe.